# SCCM Remote Control Viewer permission time-out handling workaround

Tags: remote-desktop-services, sccm

I use SCCM 2016 1702 and it's pretty good, but the situational handling when trying to Remote Control to a computer when someone is away is annoying.

I'd ideally like the connect permissions box to appear for 30 seconds, to give them the opportunity to deny, before connecting after the permissions time-out. Currently, you can only connect immediately, or have to wait for the computer to lock (and hope it actually does).

Has anyone been left wanting from the situation same as me and found a way to tweak the SCCM client to enable this or similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's working just like your "ideally", only difference is the 'timeout' time. Thing is that you need to configure your client settings.

Assuming you're using **Default Client Settings**, go to **Properties** - **Remote Tools** - **Prompt user for Remote Control permission**, be sure it's set to **Yes**.

Once you set this and your clients get the new policy, the Remote control viewer will work like below:

- Administrator Side:
  Admin start Remote Control to a client, he needs to wait for end user's approval. Also he can click **Cancel** to cancel the remote control request.
  [image]
- End User side:
  End user see a Remote control message box appear, he can click **Approve** to allow or click **Deny** to deny.
  [image]

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, Bifeng. Unfortunately, this falls short of my (seemingly ambitious) wish. I was hoping that there was a way of handling when someone is AFK, has left their session unlocked, and would otherwise be happy for me to remote onto their / already messaged to say it's OK, but forgot to wait for the box. It happens quite a lot in my company (scatty salespeople, haha). I'm going to settle for the tiered client settings profiles approach.